# error CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool' because it is not a delegate type

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

This has been driving me mad for ages. I took the following piece of working code

```
<input @onchange="@((ui) => Console.WriteLine(ui.Value))" />
```

and copied it to a new blazor component project. I then started getting the error

`error CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool' because it is not a delegate type`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As this lost me quite a lot of time and the error is very misleading I thought I'd write it up.

The issue is a missing `@using` add the following in and it all works.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
```

I'm guessing there is some extension method in that namespace that makes the magic work in the razor generated code...

Answer (score 15):

Adding the `@using` statement unfortunately didn't work for me. Apparently, you have to define the lambda expression directly inside the quotes now, without wrapping it inside `@(...)`, like this:

```
<input @onchange="changeEventArgs => Console.WriteLine(changeEventArgs.Value)" />
```

See this reference for examples:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/blazor-for-web-forms-developers/components#event-handlers

Answer (score 0):

This wasted so much of my time.

For me `Visual Studio` added ignore for the child component I was calling.

I removed the ignore from the csproj and it worked as intended

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had removed the `Shared` using statement in `_Imports.razor`

```
@using {MyProjectName}.Shared
```

I added it back and all good.

[image]